# Apple Watch check if passcode is enabled

Tags: ios, passwords, apple-watch

The Apple Watch has the Apple Pay feature and it requires a passcode to be able to use it. I need some kind of log in and I was wondering if I can use that security feature in my app. Is it possible to check if the passcode is enabled? Does any other watch app use that?

Comment: Hi Brian, I am looking for similar situation. Can you please let me know if you got anything on this?